# Collision not being registered in contact listener? [Libgdx + Box2d]

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

Problem with collision in my game: with some entities, it's not consistent with being registered in the contact listener. Specifically, my bullets and missiles often pass right through other entities/mobs, operative word being often, as sometimes they do, and I can't really ascertain the cause for this inconsistency. I've set both of them to "bullet" for continuous collision, and they don't travel obnoxiously fast, so I'm out of ideas.

Here is a video demonstrating the issue:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMLkg5r3dpo

Here is my contact listener:

```
public class Collisions implements ContactListener {

public Collisions() {       
}

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Body a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
    Body b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();

    if (a.getUserData() instanceof Bullet && b.getUserData() instanceof Enemy) {
        Bullet bullet = (Bullet) a.getUserData();
        Enemy enemy = (Enemy) b.getUserData();

        enemy.harm(10);
        bullet.kill();
    } 

    if (a.getUserData() instanceof Missile && b.getUserData() instanceof Enemy) {
        Missile missile = (Missile) a.getUserData();
        Enemy enemy = (Enemy) b.getUserData();

        enemy.harm(40);
        missile.kill();
    } 

    if (a.getUserData() instanceof Craft && b.getUserData() instanceof Enemy) {
        Craft craft = (Craft) a.getUserData();
        Enemy enemy = (Enemy) b.getUserData();

        craft.harm(5);
        enemy.harm(10);
    } 
}

@Override
public void endContact(Contact contact) {       
}

@Override
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {       
}

@Override
public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
}
```

}

Comment: Given the way you've described the problem, I would assume that the issue lies in the fact that the contacts are not being picked up at all - not that they are being processed incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to also check whether fixture B is a bullet or a missile.
From http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy

> There is no particular ordering of the A and B fixtures, so you will often need to have user data set in the fixtures or their bodies so you can tell what object the fixtures belong to. From these fixtures, you can GetBody() to find the bodies that collided.